# How to concatenate items having same Id using STUFF

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have three tables as follows:

**OrderProductVariant**

```
Id  |   ProductVariantId
----------------------------------------
1   |   22 
2   |   23
3   |   24
4   |   25
```

**ProductVariant**

```
Id  |   ProductId
----------------------------------------
22  |   34
22  |   35
23  |   36
23  |   37
24  |   38
24  |   39
```

**Product**

```
Id  |   Product
----------------------------------------
34  |   KBDMouse800 
35  |   KBDMK250
36  |   LaptopCorei7
37  |   LaptopCorei5
38  |   BluetoothMouse1000
39  |   PresentorR800
```

I want the output result to be :

```
OrderProductVariant.Id  |   Product
-----------------------------------------
1           |   KBDMouse800, KBDMK250
2           |   LaptopCorei7, LaptopCorei5
3           |   BluetoothMouse1000, PresentorR800
```

Answer (score 2):

The current query will give all the records from table `OrderProductVariant`. Maybe it's time for you to figure out how to filter non matching records.

```
SELECT  o.ID,
        STUFF((SELECT   ',' + ' ' + b.Product 
               FROM ProductVariant a
               INNER JOIN Product b ON a.ProductId = b.Id
               WHERE a.Id = o.ProductVariantId
               FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS ProductList
FROM    OrderProductVariant AS o
GROUP   BY o.ID, o.ProductVariantId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f956/15)